# MySQL set field of records within 10 seconds of the first in group

Tags: mysql

I've got a table in a MySQL database with the following columns:

- id (integer)
- ip (varchar)
- profile  (integer)
- created (datetime)
- approved (tinyint) (default null)

If records with the same id, ip and profile are inserted within 10 seconds of each other I want to set the approved flag of all but the last one set to zero. This has to happen once a day.

I tried building a query with a group by the slots and name, ip and profile but I can't figure out one query to disable all but the first.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Query to select is:

```
SELECT 
    id, ip, profile, 
    DATE_ADD('2015-10-1', INTERVAL 10 * ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-1')) DIV 10) SECOND) AS slot 
FROM test
GROUP BY slot, id, profile, ip
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: shiw us the query you already tried

Comment: So approved is DEFAULT 1? And there's no 'name' column in your table.

Comment: **approved** default is null, I added the select I use which works. But haven't got a query to update them.

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: The primary key is **id**